# Story about a Chinese based Colonization authority and their conquest of Venus

Tags: story-identification

I am looking for title, author's name for an *OLD* colonization story.

As I recall, the colonizing authority was called "The Groonhoga" (chinese?) and they colonized Venus? (I think) by raining millions of colonists down in balloon type parachutes.

Seems like there was a cutesy name for the colonists too. That's about all I really remember.

I want to think it was a Bradbury short story? But I just cant remember and can't find anything searching the net.

Anyone remember this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This **When the People Fell** - a short story by Cordwainer Smith. It was published in Galaxy Science Fiction in April, 1959. It was republished in a 2007 collection of Smith's stories by Baen Books.

[image: Cover]

*As I recall, the colonizing authority was called "The Groonhoga" (chinese?) and they colonized Venus?*

The **Goonhogo** are the successor state to China in Smith's "Instrumentality of Mankind" universe. The story is obviously from the era of SF when Venus was imagined to be a swampy, habitable environment.

> The ruler of Goonhogo (the entity that replaced China under the early Instrumentality) decrees that 82 million **Chinesians** (men, women, and children) be dropped from space, parachuting down to the surface.

Their goal is to exterminate the "loudies" - sentient bubbles native to the planet that float around and block further development.

Many colonists die in the effort, but by sheer numbers are eventually able to conquer Venus. The story contrasts Western and Chinese approaches to problem solving.

Source: [When The People Fell - Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/When_the_People_Fell)

Comment: And that issue of *Galaxy* is available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Galaxy_v17n04_1959-04#page/n145/mode/2up).